# Change url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сan you explain please.

Why returned, only the first data attribute - "link-1.html", even if I click on the second link

```
<a class="project-link" href="link-1.html" data-url="link-1.html">
<a class="project-link" href="link-2.html" data-url="link-2.html">

var toUrl = $('.project-link').attr('data-url');
  $('a').click(function() {
  window.location.hash = toUrl;

});
```

The meaning of such action - my links open through Ajax, but I want to URL displayed in the browser.

I want to make it as behance, if you click on the cards portfolio, they displayed through Ajax in the same window, but it also left open the possibility of direct appeal to the links. That's why I want to URL displayed in the browser address bar

Comment: I am not sure this is correct code both links are missing their </a> attribute hence I think where you problem is coming from.  Please confirm your markup is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get current target url by `this`

```
$('a').click(function() {
   var toUrl = $(this).data('url'); // use this as current target
   window.location.hash = toUrl;
});
```

I recommend you to use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) when you're retrieving *data attributes* (only) instead of [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpuyqeh2/)

Comment: Thx! )) And a special thank you PeterKA for the detailed explanation!

Comment: One question, how to remove # before a link?

Comment: @AntonReshetov I'm not getting your question can  you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

> **.attr( attributeName )**
>   Returns: String
>   Description: **Get the value
>   of an attribute for the first element** in the set of matched elements.

`$('.project-link')` matches more than one element. Therefore, `$('.project-link').attr('data-url')` will return the value of the `data-url` attribute for the first element in the set.

To solve this you have maintain the `context` of the clicked element as you get the attribute, and you do this by using the `this` keyword.

And if you have other event listeners attached to the element already and you do not want them to fire -- although ajax calls will abort when the user is redirected -- you can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

```
$('a').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    window.location.hash = $(this).data('url'); //this here refers to the element that was clicked.
});
```

Comment: special thank you PeterKA for the detailed explanation

Comment: Glad you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[data-url]').click(function() {
     window.location.href = $(this).data("url");
});
```

Comment: This code only applies on links with a data-url attribute

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
$('.project-link').click(function(){
     window.location.hash = $(this).data('url');
});
```